# Bootstrap model do not closed properly when using with knockout js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, knockout.js, user-experience

I am using knockout with bootstrap js.

My requirement :

- I am creating an HTML form and I have done data binding using knockout.
- After submission of this form, I am showing a message to the user in bootstrap modal.
- On closing this modal I need to reset the HTML form. SO on clicking on the close button I and doing a click binding and calling a method. Below is the snippet of that method.

```js
// Re-setting the observable  to default value
me.addStudentForClass(null);
me.parents=ko.mapping.fromJS(new parentInfoModel(undefined));
me.localGuardian=ko.mapping.fromJS(new localGuardian(undefined));
me.lastSchoolEducation=ko.mapping.fromJS(new lastSchoolEducation(undefined));
// Closing bootstrap Modal
$('modal-id').modal('hide');
// Cleaning the knockout node , to reflect the reset change 
ko.cleanNode($('#add-student')[0]);
// and binding the view model 
ko.applyBindings(app.mainViewModel, $('#add-student')[0]);
```

If we are not using below two lines of code then the modal work fine and modal got closed on clicking the close button

```js
ko.cleanNode($('#add-student')[0]);
ko.applyBindings(app.mainViewModel, $('#add-student')[0]);
```

But I need to use the above two lines of code because it needs to reset my form.

If we are delaying in cleaning the node then it works fine.

```js
function saysomething(){
   ko.cleanNode($('#add-student')[0]);
   ko.applyBindings(app.mainViewModel, $('#add-student')[0]);
     }
     setTimeout(saysomething, 500); }
```

Please help me with this. I don't want to use setTimeout.And please suggest the best practice on this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `setTimeout`, you can listen for the `hidden` event:

```
$('#modal-id').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  ko.cleanNode($('#add-student')[0]);
  ko.applyBindings(app.mainViewModel, $('#add-student')[0]);
})
```

See [Bootstrap's documentation on handling modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events).